# Alternative to three dimensional array

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

I use three dimensional array for my Floyd-Warshall Algorithm. But the problem is that I'm running out of memory, when I'm using a size over 100.

```
float[100][100][100] array= new float[100][100][100];
```

So I was thinking about alternatives. One was to use two dimensional **Float** and store them in an ArrayList. But that is not working at all, because I run into troubles with the initialization of Float, which is null instead of 0 and therefore the result is false. I do not want to change my code again, because it suits perfect also for parallelism. 
So is there a possibility to use another datastructure to store the values?

Comment: If you're running out of memory, then this whole thing needs revisionning. The fact is, that on Android devices this resource is limited (also considering a three dimentional array of 100 on each dimention). Another thing is to use a dynamic array (not exactly of length 100, but if that's what you need you might want to consider moving the calculations outside of the device). You can also paste what you've done so far ..

Comment: Are you really running out of memory? I have filled whole your array and the whole program takes only 19 MiB RAM. Where is the problem?

Comment: 100 is just an example, but sometimes I need maybe 1000x1000x1000 and thats not possible. Anyway I was actually thinking to use this ArrayLists, because I could remove List entries if I do not need them anymore. This would reduce the memory and could help me to run my algorithm. But as I mentioned it won't work with my algorithm. The problem is the null, 0 stuff and maybe also other things with do not fit with Float.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays are objects, so you're not limited to using wrapper types. You can make an array list of `float[][]`.

Anyway, 100x100x100 = 1000 000 floats should take about 4 MB of memory. It's not nothing, but doesn't seem unreasonably large amount of memory. Are you sure that the problem is not somewhere else? Is it possible you're holding on to objects you no longer need and could be garbage collected?

Comment: How? I couldn't figure out how I can use `float[][]` in an ArrayList? I always found that I can use only `Float[][]`.

Comment: What do you mean "how"? What have you tried? list=new ArrayList<float[][]>(); list.add(new float[100][100]);

Comment: Okay it seems that it is working. My other problem is now how I can set values? I can get values with `list.get(i)[j][k]`, which means that i is the row of the ArrayList, j and k my entry of the `float[][]` array. But how can I set a value? list.set([j][j], array[i][j]) is not working.

Comment: The `get` method returns an array so you can write `list.get(i)[j][k] = number`, as long as `i` is a valid index. (If it's not you would have to add new arrays to the list)

Answer (score 3):

A four-byte float in a 3D cube of size 100 will take up 4,000,000 bytes at least. That's a rather large chunk.

They'll take up at least that much space no matter what data structure you use if you have them all in-memory at the same time.

You may want to consider moving them *out* of memory and only bringing them in as needed.

The best way to do that will depend on the sort of processing you need to do on them. For example, if you were doing straight sequential processing such as with the following pseudo-code:

```
for i = 0 to 99:
    for j = 0 to 99:
        for k = 0 to 99:
            loadAndDoSomethingWith (i, j, k)
flushData()

currentlyLoaded = -1
float buffer[100]

def loadAndDoSomethingWith (i, j, k):
    if i * 100 + j != currentlyLoaded:
        flushData()
        currentlyLoaded = i * 100 + j
        read buffer from file #currentlyLoaded
    doSomethingWith (buffer, k)

def flushData():
    if currentlyLoaded != -1:
        write buffer to file #currentlyLoaded
```

then you could just bring in a single dimension at a time (100 floats).

You could do a similar scheme with *multiple* buffers to take car of the more complex cases, such as if you need data from many more places in the data structure. You should try to match the buffering strategy to your algorithms so as to avoid thrashing as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO there is not much you can do about it if you need to have 100x100x100 floats. Float objects need more memory than the primitive floats, so there is no point in using them to reduce memory consumption. There are only two things you can do:
1. Change/optimize your algorithm so that it uses less numbers.
2. In AndroidManifest use:

```
<application
    android:name="com.myApp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
   android:largeHeap="true"
```

so that you increase the size of the heap you use.
 Just my two pennies.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to allocate 4byte*100*100*100 ~ 2MB of **consecutive** memory from JVM which is quite huge. Instead try creating object with three float attributes. You can initilize attibutes with whatever value you want.

```
class Node{
private float u =0;
private float v =0;
private float l =0;
}
```

Comment: each one-dimentional array of size 100 is an individual object, so `new float[100][100][100]` allocates 10101 separate objects. Why do you think they require consecutive memory?

Comment: How would a Node class with three `float` variables help if the OP needs a million floats? 1,000,000 isn't even divisible by 3.

Comment: @Joni  With use of array, JVM has obligation to allocate consecutive memory. IF we use any data structure other than array (i.e. linked list or object), JVM can allocate any available memory on heap.

Comment: Using objects, the JVM is also obligated to allocate consecutive memory for the object's fields, just like for arrays.